# How to display Data from two model without creating new model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two models with one common field (email). I using viewset.ModelViewset to list and create data in both the models.

My models.py:

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    """Database model for Schema """

    name= models.TextField()
    version = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Status(models.Model):
    """ Model For status """
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True )
    status = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

my view.py:

```
class StatusViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.Status.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StatusSerializer


class SchemaViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    queryset = models.Schema.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchemaSerializer
```

I want to overide List function of Status Viewset to display entire detail of that user. 
For ex: from schema viewset i have created :

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Yatharth",
    "version": "1.1",
    "email": "yatharth@test.com"
}
```

and From Staus viewset i have POST the status of Email: yatharth@test.com to Active. From GET of Status VIewset I want to display data like this:

```
{
    "name": "Yatharth",
    "version": "1.1",
    "email": "yatharth@test.com"
    "status": "Active"

}
```

How to do this?
I found select_related and prefetch_related in Django ORM but don't know how to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your database, I do not find any reason to create separate table for `Status`. If you still have to create separate table, you should manage relationship between these two using `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`. It will make your task a lot easy. For your current structure, you will have to write your serializer like this

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_status(self, instance):
        status = Status.objects.filter(email=instance.email)
        if status.exists():
            return status.first().status

    class Mete:
        model = Schema
        fields = ('name', 'version', 'email', 'status')
```

In simple word, create a `SerializerMethodField` and define its logic of getting data on the basis of `Schema` object.

If you change your model

```
class Schema(models.Model):
    """Database model for Schema """

    name= models.TextField()
    version = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True )


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Status(models.Model):
    """ Model For status """
    schema = models. OneToOneField(to=Schema, related_name='schema_status')
    status = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

This structre will help you accessing respective `Status` object of `Schema` like `schema_obj.schema_status` where `schema_status` is `related_name`. You should keep in mind that this will work only work when you have an object of `Status` against a `Schema` object. Therefore I have put `if hasattr(instance, 'schema_status')` in below serialzer `get_status` method.

Serializer

```
class SchemaSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    status = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_status(self, instance):
        if hasattr(instance, 'schema_status'):
            return instance.schema_status.status

    class Mete:
        model = Schema
        fields = ('name', 'version', 'email', 'status')
```

Comment: email = models.ForeignKey(Schema, on_delete=models.CASCADE). I have updated the status model. How do i do than?

Comment: When you will use ForeignKey, you will be able to access status by using reverse relationship. BTW why you need separate table for Status? Do you have multiple status against each Schema object?

Comment: My use case have two table containing 1 common field. In table 1 i have some details for all the user. In table 2  some additional details have been added to some users. So i want to display all the details (old +new) for those users in table 2

Comment: You should use OneToOneField in Status table instead. Use `related_name` in Status table (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield). This will help you in reverse lookup. I will update my answer.