# How to use nested serializers with Django rest mixins

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to implement `CRUD` operation in Django-REST framework with multiple models.
The goal is to perform `CRUD` operation ron multiple table when the API call is made.

I use `mixins` from REST framework https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#mixins

I have found some relevant examples but still, my serializer is only returning the fields from the `Student` model for `CRUD`operation. I'm not able to see the `Course` models field in REst api ui.

**PROBLEM**
I can't get the fields from `Homework` and `Course` models.

[How to display Data from two model without creating new model in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61402484/how-to-display-data-from-two-model-without-creating-new-model-in-django)

[use of mixins class defined in Django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71111159/use-of-mixins-class-defined-in-django-rest-framework)

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
                      primary_key=True, editable=False)
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=18)

   

class Course(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    courseName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    courseYear = models.IntegerField(default=2021)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, related_name='courses')


class Homework(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    hwName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hwPossScore = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='homeworks', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"


class HomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = __all__


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"
###I combine both Student and Course into one
class All_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    students = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    homeworks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    courses = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_students(self, obj):
        students = obj.student_set.all()
        serializer = StudentSerializer(students, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_homeworks(self, obj):
        homeworks = obj.homework_set.all()
        serializer = HomeworkSerializer(homeworks, many=True, read_only=True)  
        return serializer.data

    def get_courses(self, obj):
        courses = obj.courses_set.all()
        serializer = CourseSerializer(courses, many=True, read_only=True)  
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('student_id','firstName','age','homeworks','courses')
```

**views.py**

```
 class Main_mixins(generics.GenericAPIView, 
                                mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    serializer_class = All_Serializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'student_id'

    def get(self, request, student_id=None):
        if student_id:
           return self.retrieve(request, student_id)
        else:
            return self.list(request)
    
    def post(self, request):
        return self.create(request)
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
    
    
    def put(self, request, student_id=None):
        return self.update(request, student_id=None, homeworks, courses)
```

thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you trying to do.

The model of `course` and `homework` belongs to ***one*** student or to have ***many*** of the student? Pardon me if I miss-understanding the purpose of your implementation.

But if you want your student `queryset` include a course and homework fields. You may try the code below.

***models.py***

```
class Student(models.Model):
   student_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True,
                     primary_key=True, editable=False)
   firstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   age = models.IntegerField(default=18)

   def get_course_set(self):
      return Course.objects.filter(student_id=self)

   def get_homework_set(self):
      return Homework.objects.filter(student_id=self)


class Course(models.Model):
    ...


class Homework(models.Model):
    ...
```

***serializers.py***

```
class HomeworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Homework
        fields = __all__


class CourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = "__all__"


class StudentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course = CourseSerializer(source="get_course_set", many=True, read_only=True)
    homework = HomeworkSerializer(source="get_homework_set", many=True, read_only=True)
  
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = "__all__"

# Remove All_Serializer
# class All_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      ...
```

***views.py***

```
class Main_mixins(generics.GenericAPIView, 
                                mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                                mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                                mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                                mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                                mixins.DestroyModelMixin):

    # Change from All_Serializer to StudentSerializer
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'student_id'

    ...
```